# C style char arrays - How many bytes do we store?

Tags: c++, arrays, char, byte

```
char firstName[32];
```

I understand that each char occupies 1 byte in memory.  So does the above occupy 32 bytes of memory?

Am I missing a pointer that takes up memory too or is this just 32 bytes?

Comment: The size of an array is the number of elements times the size of each element, per the standard. So yes, since you have 32 elements and each has a size of one (`sizeof(char)` is always one), the total size is 32.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

No, that takes up exactly 32 bytes of memory.
There is no pointer.

This is often an area of confusion, since an array name silently "decays" to a "char*"

```
char* fname = firstName;
```

So, `firstName` may be of type `const char*`, but it is not itself a char* variable.  It is exactly like:

```
 int x = 5;
```

`x` is int variable and takes up space.  `5` on the other hand, is just a constant value of int type.  It takes of no space; it's just a value.

Answer (score 2):

It occupies exactly 32 bytes of memory.Internally everything an address.Variables are only for our understanding.

Answer (score 1):

This is just 32 bytes. The name of the array sometimes *acts like* a pointer to the first element, but it *is not* a pointer.

Answer (score 1):

That takes up 32 bytes.  It will hold a 31-character string (the other byte is for the null string terminator).

Comment: I'd say *can* hold a "31-character null terminated string". It doesn't have to be null-terminated, or even a string.

Answer (score 1):

The statement `char firstName[32]` creates an array of 32 characters, or 32 bytes, on the **stack**. Because it's on the stack, the compiler knows exactly where it is in relation to the stack pointer. The compiler will hardcode the address of the array into any operations that use it; there's no need for storing a pointer to it.

It's important to note that if you attempt to pass this array as a function argument, it will degrade into a **pointer** to the array, because C++ doesn't allow passing primitive arrays by value. Most people who are new to C++ would expect it to pass a copy of the array.

Comment: It's not necessarily on the stack.  It could be a global. It could be part of a struct.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to go when you need, e.g. 32 bytes, to store your data. The difference in these two versions:

```
// version 1
char *firstName = new char[32];

// version 2
char firstName[32];
```

is that for version 1 the space your data allocated on the *heap* and you have to free before the program ends, whereas in version 2 the space is on the *stack*. Both will give you a variable that points to the first byte of your available space and this space is 32 bytes in both cases. People will argue that there are reasons why you might want to [choose one over the other](https://www.gribblelab.org/CBootCamp/7_Memory_Stack_vs_Heap.html), but that is a different story.

**sizeof( firstName )**

The interesting point is what sizeof would return and this is the size of a char pointer (depends on your system and compiler) for version 1 and 32 for version 2. Keep in mind what another user mentioned, passing *firstName* to a function degrades it into a pointer.

Answer (score 0):

#### Complementing the answers above:



A pointer to char occupies 4 bytes in the 32-bit architecture, whereas in the 64-bit architecture it occupies 8. In the example, it occupies 4.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define SIZE 32


int main()
{
  char array[SIZE];
  char *ptr = (char*)array;

  printf("\nsize of array: %i bytes", sizeof(array)); 
  printf("\nsize of pointer: %i bytes", sizeof(ptr));
  printf("\naddress array on the stack: %p", &array); 
  printf("\naddress reference: %p", ptr);
  printf("\naddress pointer to array on the stack: %p", &ptr);
  

/*
    1 char -----  1 byte
    32 characters ---- 32 bytes 
*/
  return 0;
}
```

We can also allocate space in the heap for the 32-byte array:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define SIZE 32

int main() 
{
    char array[SIZE];

    char *malloc_pointer = (char*)malloc(sizeof(array)); // a pointer on stack pointing out 32 bytes on heap
  
    printf("\naddress malloc_pointer on the stack: %p", &malloc_pointer);
    printf("\nsize of pointer to heap: %i bytes", sizeof(malloc_pointer));

    free(malloc_pointer); // clean 
    
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

In the debug version there are also bytes stored beyond the array (on some compilers) to check for writing after the array. In the release version it should be 32 bytes plus one int on the stack (probably) to store the address.

Comment: If it's not dynamically allocated, there are no ints on the stack.  The address is known at compile-time, so it doesn't need to be stored.

Comment: Why would there be any need to store the address on the stack?  Nor would that be an `int`, if it existed, but rather a `char *`, which is not necessarily the same thing.

Comment: Sorry for my english I had the dynamic case in mind when I entered probably.